# Monero daemon in docker container exits for no reason

Tags: docker, monero

I wanted to make a monero daemon and monero rpc server in two different containers connected to each other
this is my docker-compose.yaml file:

```
# docker-compose.yaml file
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 12345
      POSTGRES_DB: db
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  monero_daemon:
    build: ./monero_daemon
    ports:
      - "18081:18081"

  monero_rpc:
    build: ./monero_rpc
    ports:
      - "18088:18088"
    depends_on:
      - monero_daemon

  web:
    build: .
    environment:
      DB_HOST: db
      DB_NAME: db
      DB_USER: user
      DB_PASSWORD: 12345
      DB_PORT: 5432
      DEBUG: 'True'
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - monero_rpc
```

this is the Dockerfile for monero_daemon container:

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN  apk update && apk add monero 

CMD ["monerod"]
```

and this is the Dockerfile for monero_rpc:

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN  apk update && apk add monero 

RUN monero-wallet-cli --generate-new-wallet mywallet --password '' --mnemonic-language English 

CMD monero-wallet-rpc --daemon-port 18081 --daemon-host monero_daemon --wallet-file mywallet --password "" --rpc-bind-port 18088
```

the problem is that the monero_daemon starts with no error but suddenly it exits with code 0.
this is the output of docker-compose up --build:

```
monero_daemon_1  | 2023-12-04 22:55:38.150      I Monero 'Fluorine Fermi' (v0.18.2.2-release)
monero_daemon_1  | 2023-12-04 22:55:38.151      I Initializing cryptonote protocol...
monero_daemon_1  | 2023-12-04 22:55:38.151      I Cryptonote protocol initialized OK
monero_daemon_1  | 2023-12-04 22:55:38.151      I Initializing core...
monero_daemon_1  | 2023-12-04 22:55:38.151      I Loading blockchain from folder /root/.bitmonero/lmdb ...
monero_daemon_1  | 2023-12-04 22:55:38.225      I Loading checkpoints
monero_daemon_1  | 2023-12-04 22:55:38.230      I Core initialized OK
monero_daemon_1  | 2023-12-04 22:55:38.233      I Initializing p2p server...
monero_daemon_1  | 2023-12-04 22:55:38.235      I p2p server initialized OK
monero_daemon_1  | 2023-12-04 22:55:38.236      I Initializing core RPC server...
monero_daemon_1  | 2023-12-04 22:55:38.236      I Binding on 127.0.0.1 (IPv4):18081
monero_daemon_1  | 2023-12-04 22:55:38.260      I core RPC server initialized OK on port: 18081
monero_daemon_1  | 2023-12-04 22:55:38.260      I Starting core RPC server...
monero_daemon_1  | 2023-12-04 22:55:38.266      I core RPC server started ok
monero_daemon_1  | 2023-12-04 22:55:38.273      I Starting p2p net loop...
monero_daemon_1  | 2023-12-04 22:55:38.281      I EOF on stdin, exiting
monero_daemon_1  | 
monero_daemon_1  | 2023-12-04 22:55:38.310      I p2p net loop stopped
db_1             | 2023-12-04 22:55:37.200 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
monero_daemon_1  | 2023-12-04 22:55:38.326      I Stopping core RPC server...
monero_daemon_1  | 2023-12-04 22:55:38.326      I Node stopped.
monero_rpc_1     | This is the RPC monero wallet. It needs to connect to a monero
monero_rpc_1     | daemon to work correctly.
monero_rpc_1     | 
monero_rpc_1     | Monero 'Fluorine Fermi' (v0.18.2.2-release)
monero_rpc_1     | Logging to monero-wallet-rpc.log
monero_daemon_1  | 2023-12-04 22:55:38.363      I Deinitializing core RPC server...
monero_rpc_1     | 2023-12-04 22:55:39.476      W Loading wallet...
monero_daemon_1  | 2023-12-04 22:55:38.364      I Deinitializing p2p...
monero_daemon_1  | 2023-12-04 22:55:39.282      I Deinitializing core...
monero_daemon_1  | 2023-12-04 22:55:39.290      I Stopping cryptonote protocol...
monero_daemon_1  | 2023-12-04 22:55:39.290      I Cryptonote protocol stopped successfully
db_1             | 2023-12-04 22:55:37.211 UTC [29] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2023-12-04 22:49:51 UTC
db_1             | 2023-12-04 22:55:37.233 UTC [29] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
db_1             | 2023-12-04 22:55:37.246 UTC [29] LOG:  redo starts at 0/1971A48
db_1             | 2023-12-04 22:55:37.246 UTC [29] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/1971A80: expected at least 24, got 0
db_1             | 2023-12-04 22:55:37.246 UTC [29] LOG:  redo done at 0/1971A48 system usage: CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.00 s
monero_daemon_1 exited with code 0
```

as you can see some second after the daemon started it exited.
do you know what i should do?